# Exit code = 13 when Eclipse starting

Tags: java, eclipse

I been having this error on my eclipse on start up. My eclipse.ini is the one below:

```
-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
-showsplash org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
--launcher.defaultAction openFile
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I followed multiple solutions even on eclipse forums but the error is not going away.

The **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe** is the directory were I recently updated to jdk1.8.0_60 and jre1.8.0_60

Comment: Note: I still have installed in the same path the jdk1.8.0_05 and in other path the jre1.8.0_25 but I read that his will not be an issue, correct?

Comment: Try to reinstall jdk as well as the eclipse, i had the same issue once

Comment: I have also seen this before, and agree with @JaiSharma. Attempt to reinstall the JDK first, and then eclipse. It fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I will try it, but just to verify, is it a problem to have the other older versions of jdk and jre installed in same location?

Comment: It worked! I reinstalled the JDK and downloaded Eclipse MARS, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have the `-vm` specification in `eclipse.ini` wrong. As documented in the [eclipse.ini wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM), `-vm` and the path to the Java executable must be on *separate* lines. Like this

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe
```

If you have them on the same line, Eclipse won't use the value at all and it will fall back on using whatever JVM it finds first on your system path. In your case, it was finding a JVM of the wrong bit-ness, producing the 13 exit code.